# Check external redirection with Codeception

Tags: php, testing, codeception

I want to check something like this:

```
<?php

$I->amOnPage('/go/google');
$I->seeCurrentUrlEquals('http://google.com');
```

But I get error:

```
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'http://google.com'
+''

Scenario Steps:
2. I see current url equals "http://google.com"
1. I am on page "/go/google"
```

Idea is just to check if users was redirected to external resource.

Comment: What does the page that does the redirecting (`/go/google/`) look like?

Comment: @Jordan, it's just a script that redirects user using redirect header... And now I'm thinking I know what to do :D

Answer (score 4):

Codeception's `seeCurrentUrlEquals()` and `seeCurrentUrlMatches()` methods are, unfortunately, misnamed as they do not allow assertions to be made against the entire URL but rather only against the URI parts.

I solved this by declaring the following method in my Helper class:

```
public function seeFullCurrentURLEquals($value)
{
    return ($this->getModule('PhpBrowser')->client->getHistory()->current()->getUri() == $value);
}
```

Then, in the scenario, you can simply do something like:

```
$I->seeFullCurrentUrlEquals('google.com');
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution.

Note 1. Maybe the things have changed in a year, but instead of returning a boolean value, helper method must call the assertion.

My method looks like this:
```php
    public function seeFullCurrentURLEquals($value)
    {
        $currentUrl = $this->getModule('PhpBrowser')->client->getHistory()->current()->getUri();
        codecept_debug('Current URL: ' . $currentUrl);
        $this->assertEquals($currentUrl,  $value, 'Current URL ' . $currentUrl . ' is not equal to ' . $value);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I would improve @rickroyce´s comment by swapping out line 2

```
$I->wait(2);
```

with something like

```
$I->waitForElement('#gbqfq', 30);
```

which waits for the google search input field and is more robust then just assuming 2 seconds is enough that the page is loaded.

The full example would be then

```
<?php

$I->amOnPage('/go/google');
$I->waitForElement('#gbqfq', 30);
$I->seeCurrentUrlEquals('http://google.com');
```

(Normally it would put the addition as comment but since I do not have enough reputation it is an answer :))

Answer (score 2):

As @gopherIT mentioned, Codeception does not check the domain name portion of the URL when using those functions.

If you're using **phpBrowser**, here are a couple of options.

---

1. I've written two functions `verifyRedirect()` and `verifyNoRedirect()` which can be used for this purpose.  You simply pop the code inside `_support/Helper/Acceptance.php`.

   And then can test like this...

   ```
   $I->verifyRedirect('http://www2.ames.net.au/', 'http://www.ames.net.au/', 301);
   ```

   View code: https://gist.github.com/SimonEast/b550e04300ac56cb5ac8eea704fccdfa

---

2. GaryJones has also put together another (slightly more complex) variation for testing redirections and posted it on Github:

   https://gist.github.com/GaryJones/284eea905cff882cc7cb

   It allows you to run tests like this...

   ```
   $I = new RedirectsTester($scenario);
   $I->wantTo('check 301 redirects are working');

   // First, test /login/ page gets rewritten to https://
   $I->seePermanentRedirectToHttpsFor('login/');
   $I->seePermanentRedirectToHttpsFor('login/?redirect_to=foo');

   // For all other redirects, a Location header is sent, so we stop the redirect
   // and just check that header instead.
   $I->followRedirects(false);

   // External
   $I->sendHead('facebook');
   $I->seePermanentRedirectTo('https://www.facebook.com/DanielsTrading');

   // Internal link
   $I->sendHead('don-debartolo/access');
   $I->seePermanentRedirectTo('ddebartolo/#account');
   ```

   Reviewing his source code might help with further customization if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet of code that could help :

```
$uri_to_redirect = '/use_stackoverflow';
$redirected_to_uri = '/love_stackoverflow';

$I->wantToTest( 'if rediecting works well from : '.$uri_to_redirect.' to : '.$redirected_to_uri );
$I->amOnUrl( $mydomain.$uri_to_redirect );
$I->seeCurrentUrlEquals( $redirected_to_uri );
```

You need to keep in head that "seeCurrentUrlEquals" verify the URI, and not the URL.

Regards

Comment: The `amOnUrl` function does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of browser do you want to use? The most browsers need a bit of time to interpret an redirection. After visiting the site "/go/google", the test runs immediatly the url check and this could be faster then the browser can do the redirect. Give it a little more time.

Try:

```
<?php

$I->amOnPage('/go/google');
$I->wait(2);
$I->seeCurrentUrlEquals('http://google.com');
```

Kind regards

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't it be better checking the response code?

```
$I->amOnPage('/go/google');
$I->seeResponseCodeIs(302);
$I->seeHttpHeader('Location', 'http://google.com');
```

Comment: I've been trying to do this, but it seems that codeception only populates the client->getInternalRequest data with the ends result i.e. the 200, and not the 301 or 302.

Comment: @GaryJ this is because following redirects is enabled by default. Add before:  `$client->followRedirects(false);`